# Is there a way to reduce resource usage when reading and writing large dataframes with polars?

Tags: python, pandas, resources, python-polars

For my specific problem I have been converting ".csv" files to ".parquet" files. The CSV files on disk are about 10-20 GB each.

Awhile back I have been using ".SAS7BDAT" files of similar size to convert to ".parquet" files of similar data but now I get them in CSVs so this might not be a good control, but I used the pyreadstat library to read these files in (with multi-threading on in the parameter, which didn't make a difference for some reason) and pandas to write. It was also a tiny bit faster but I feel the code ran on a single thread, and it took a week to convert all my data.

This time, I tried the polars library and it was blazing fast. The **CPU usage was near 100%, memory usage was also quite high**. I tested this on a single file which would have taken hours, only to complete in minutes. The problem is that it uses too much of my computer's resources and my PC stalls. **VSCode has crashed on some occasions. I have tried passing in the low memory parameter but it still uses a lot of resources**. My suspicion is with the "reader.next_batches(500)" variable but I don't know for sure.

Regardless, **is there a way to limit the CPU and memory usage while running this operation so I can at least browse the internet/listen to music while this runs in the background**? With pandas the process is too slow, with polars the process is fast but my PC becomes unusable at times. See image for the code I used.

Thanks.
[image: The code I used]

I tried the low memory parameter with polars but memory usage was still quite high. I was expecting to at least use my PC while this worked in the background. My hope is to use 50-80% of my PC's resources such that enough resources are free for other work while the files are being converted.

Comment: Have you tried setting the `POLARS_MAX_THREADS` environment variable before importing `polars`?  Perhaps leaving a CPU core for other tasks might be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

I see you're on Windows so convert your notebook into a py script then from the command line run

```
start /low python yourscript.py
```

And/or use task manager to lower the priority of your python process once it's running.